# Best b/w Factory Girl, machinist and fabrication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

To test a big application, which is best b/w Factory Girl, machinist or fabrication.
as Factory Girl make real objects so it hits database and makes testing slow, and i want to run tests fast?

Is machinist and fabrication are good alternatives to Factory Girl?
and also want to run all callbacks of models like 'after_save' etc.

Answer (score 0):

FactoryGirl has methods that do not hit the database, like:

```
FactoryGirl.build(:object)
```

Comment: please let me know, can i test after_save callbacks with above FactoryGirl.build methods and how?

Comment: Ronak, I think you are not able to do it on the build. But I'm sure that you can have associated objects on create. Please, check out this post - http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/23673635798/remove-duplication-with-factorygirls-traits

Answer (score 0):

I think that answer should be related to not performance but convenience. I used to both Facticator and FactoryGirl and I bet that FactoryGirl is more convenient and allows to do some things which other fabricators don't provide (for example traits, automatic building associations and etc.). FactoryGirl also has a bigger community. So my answer is that FactoryGirl the best

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
FactoryGirl.build(:object)
```

..and use `after_build` callback. You can build associated objects, too. However, they will not have ID's until you save the object(s).

Comment: little confuse, to test a controller should i use mock & stubs 'save' call or just let store object into database, which is best?

Answer (score 0):

In fabrication, you have a Fabricate.attributes_for(:model) that do a kind of *.build* but if you have nested models, and you fabricate them you *build* the main object but the nested have been created....

But... if you don't save all data how you REALLY test your app?...

If you want to create directly, can do *Fabricate(:model)*

Good Luck ^^